# Mendix setup problem - suggested code not working

Tags: node.js, mendix

I'm dipping my toe into Mendix Typescript SDK and followed the instructions on https://docs.mendix.com/apidocs-mxsdk/mxsdk/setting-up-your-development-environment.

I then followed https://docs.mendix.com/apidocs-mxsdk/mxsdk/creating-your-first-script to create a script to try it out.

However, I'm getting the following error to the code `script.ts` suggested on this page:

```
error TS2554: Expected 1-2 arguments, but got 0.
30     return dm.load();
      ~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/mendixmodelsdk/dist/gen/domainmodels.d.ts:583:14
583         load(callback: (element: DomainModel) => void, forceRefresh?: boolean): void;
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
An argument for 'callback' was not provided.
Found 1 error.

return dm.load();
```

I'm not NodeJS savvy - but I can tell the parameter passed in to `load()` is incorrect - just doesn't exists although `load()` is defined to take a parameter. But then, why the error to a script on the suggested setup? I'll attack this issue. But need help on where to start.

This "feels" like a version difference/setup error. But I've seen no errors anywhere else while I was setting it up.

What am i missing?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't have experience in making that particular example script work; it might as well be out of date. In my own script, I'm loading the data model with the `loadAsPromise` function, as indicated in the script in the article [Generate Code from the Model](https://docs.mendix.com/apidocs-mxsdk/mxsdk/generating-code-from-the-model).

```
async function serializeToJs() {
    const workingCopy = await project.createWorkingCopy();
    const domainModelInterface = workingCopy.model().allDomainModels().filter(dm => dm.containerAsModule.name === moduleName)[0];

    try {
        const domainModel = await loadAsPromise(domainModelInterface);
        console.log(JavaScriptSerializer.serializeToJs(domainModel)); //print out the generated JavaScript
        console.log("success!")
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(`error: ${error}`);
    }
}
```